# Нахождение четырехзначных чисел

Tags: python, математика

Нужно найти сколько существует четырехзначных чисел таких, что если из него вычесть число записанное тем же цифрами, но в обратном порядке получиться куб натурального числа.

Comment: Только уточните, каким подходом пользоваться. Если во множестве простых чисел учитывается "0" - тогда Ваш ответ будет лежать в рамках от 9 до 30. А если нет - тогда ответ будет не более 21. А лучше отошлите адресату сразу оба варианта. Так Вас не срежут сыграв на том что использовать нужно было другой подход.

Comment: Неверно написал, Harry подкорректировал мои подсчеты. Если с "0" - то вариантов от 90 до 111.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Так не устроит?

```
def isCube(x):
    y = int(x**(1/3)+0.5)
    return y*y*y == x
```

Ну, а с учетом того, что кубический корень можно брать и из отрицательных чисел...

```
def isCube(x):
    y = int(x**(1/3)+0.5)
    return y*y*y == x

count = 0

for i in range(1000,10000):
    y = i-int(str(i)[::-1])
    if y < 0: y = -y
    if isCube(y):
        count = count + 1

print(count)
```

Но - по напоминанию @V.March - тогда это уже не натуральные числа (0 - тоже не натуральное число...), так что

```
def isCube(x):
    y = int(x**(1/3)+0.5)
    return y*y*y == x

count = 0

for i in range(1000,10000):
    y = i-int(str(i)[::-1])
    if y <= 0: continue;
    if isCube(y):
        count = count + 1

print(count)
```

И вообще :) -

```
print(126)
```

Comment: А не будет ли кубический корень из отрицательного числа отрицательным числом? Если да - тогда это не натуральное число.

Comment: @V.March Тогда надо подправить :) Спасибо за указание.

Comment: Еще момент, есть второй подход во множестве натуральных чисел, где присутствует "0". Тобишь 1111-1111=0. И корень из 0 будет 0.

Comment: Можно правда схитрить и если множество натуральных чисел по требованиям должно включать 0, то просто добавить к искомому результату 9. Но тогда это будет не программное вычисление.

Comment: Относительно "0" я бы не был так категоричен: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number

Comment: @V.March Известное расхождение американской школы и нашей. Но у нас же **RU** StackOverflow? :) https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE И, кстати, далеко не 9 - например, `1221-1221` - тоже ноль :)

Comment: Это спорный вопрос, верно, но обе версии есть в международных стандартах. А ссылку привел на анг версию, так как ссылка на ру версию у меня длинная очень получалась. А как вставить линк под другим названием - не помню.

Comment: А верно, таки не учел внутренние цифры. тогда должно быть нулевых вариантов всего 90. Спасибо! Правду говорят, одна голова хорошо. а две - лучше ))

Answer (score 2):

Вот так можно проверить:

```
def is_cube(num):
    c = int(x**(1/3)+0.1)
    return c**3 == x
```

А еще можно самостоятельно написать функцию для нахождения кубического корня по алгоритму из Википедии.

Comment: Вы уверены, что где-то корень кубический не окажется ####.9999999?

Comment: Не учел это. Понял ошибку, исправил код

Comment: Проще добавлять 0.5 - это будет обычное округление до целого.

Answer (score 1):

Исходя из условий задачи, куб не может быть больше 9999. Таких кубов не очень много - 22 в кубе уже больше 10000. Поэтому можно создать сет со значениями кубов чисел до 21 включительно и проверять результат на вхождение в сет. Тогда не потребуется каждый раз вычислять кубический корень:

```
cubes = {x ** 3 for x in range(1,22)} # множество значений кубов, без учета 0
total = 0

for number in range(1000, 10000):
    diff = number - int(str(number)[::-1])
    if diff < 0:
        continue
    if diff in cubes:
        total = total + 1

print(total)
```